# Creating visual similar to excel table in PowerBi

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a excel sheet which has columns such as Sr. No , Products, Owner
The data is in the format like
[image: data]

As one serial number has many Products under it, after importing this data in PowerBi and while creating a table visual, PowerBi takes the empty serial number as null and do not link it with its parent Serial number.

I tried creating relationship and modelling the data, but it did not help.
Expected result is that, after creating a table visual , Serial Number 1 must be linked to all values under it and similar for other Sr. No

Comment: Is this the raw data in Excel, or is this result of a pivot table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what `filldown` is for:

```
Table.FillDown(Source,{"Sr. no"})
```

Comment: Can you give me the exact formula that I can use, in PowerQuery Editor, my table name is Table 1(Data) and the column name of Serial number column is S.no

Comment: Just right click on the column (in powerQuery editor, then select fill > down. Code will be generated.

Comment: But now , when I create a table visual, Sr. No appears before every row. It does not exactly look like the one in the Excel

Answer (score 2):

In Excel, your Products B and M are not linked to any Sr.No. If you try to do a vlookup, index / match, or pivot table, you will see they are not linked in Excel. In PowerBI it will be the same. If you want Products B and M linked to Sr.No 1 and 3, you need to use filldown like the other user suggested. That applies in both PowerBI and in Excel.

You can get the Power BI table to 'look' like the Excel table, but it is only because the Products are sorted A-Z, it has nothing to do with linking them to Sr. No.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ike's answer with fill down looks good, but for me, the preference would be to fix the source. You are right. It's a poorly constructed excel table